# Convert A frequency weight to Z frequency weight

Tags: filters, frequency, sound, tone-generation

I want to get the SPL of a monotonic sound like a 1khz tone but the problem is that I have a SPL meter which gives data in terms of *A frequency weight*. Is it possible to get the SPL of a 1khz signal, which is my dominant frequency and its amplitude is higher than any other frequency, by means of mentioned SPL meter? I want to have the exact amplitude and I do not want my data to be manipulated by SPL meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-weighting is basically no frequency weighting.

For pure sine waves, you can simply subtract the A-weighting for the specific frequency from the SPL meter reading using a table like this https://www.nti-audio.com/en/support/know-how/frequency-weightings-for-sound-level-measurements

Example: for a 500Hz sine wave you have
$$L_Z = L_A + 3.2dB$$

If the signal contains more than one frequency, you cannot calculate the Z-weighted SPL from the A-weighted SPL.